# Linear or (n log n) time complexity

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity

```
function f(n) {
  var cnt = 0;

  for (var j = n; j > 0; j = Math.floor(j / 5)) {
    var k = j * 2;

    while (k > 0) {
      cnt++;
      k -= 5;
    }
  }

  return cnt;
}
```

Is time complexity of this function `O(n)` or `O(n log n)` and **why**?
The tests produce close to linear growth, but that's also true for some `n log n` algorithms, right?

Comment: When testing, be sure to disable all runtime optimisations. They can have a very big impact on your measurements...

Comment: @alesc: I think he measures `cnt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The work that is done in each iteration of the `for` loop forms a series that can be approximated by a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series) (it's an approximation as the floor and -=5, but can be used as an upper bound).

The sum of the progression is going to be equal to the first item multiplied by some constant, the same way as 1+1/2+1/4... = 2.

So this is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

It is `2 * sum(5^j / 5) for j = 0 to log_{5}(n) = O(n)`. It is basically a geometric progression. A link to the Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume complexity as iterations coun **C** complexiti of **for** is C=ln(n)/ln(5) and of while is C=k/5 (k = j*2) Whole complexity is

```
N = 5^m  ->  m = ln(n)/ln(5)

C(n) = sum(k = 0->m)(5^k/5) * 2

C(n) = (1 - 5^m)/(1 - 5) * 2 = (n + 1)/2

O(n) = n
```

Comment: you cannot simply multiply those two numbers.

Comment: I divided by 2, cause of that.

Comment: Makes no difference. You got an upper bound, but a to loose one.

Comment: Yes my mistake. Let me change it.

Answer (score -1):

You have the for cycle which goes from i=1 to log(n) and while cycle has length of 2*n/5^i * 1/5. 
Let's count the summ: 2/5*n * (summ from i=1 to log(n): 1/5^i) the summ is geom. progression so it's limited. So you have O(c*n) where c is a constant.

Comment: "So it's"... that's a huge, and incorrect gap in your explanation.